# Interact with element imported from another file on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 files: a.html, b.html, c.html. When I load a.html, I have a a.js where on the onload I load there b.html and c.html like this

```
$.ajax({url: "../b.html", success: function(result){
    $("#topbar").html(result);
}});
$.ajax({url: "../c.html", success: function(result){
    $("#sidebar").html(result);
}});
```

This part is loaded correctly. I also have a menu.js where an element with id 'idElementMenu' from b.html has a listener to an onclick event. The thing is that when I click on the element 'idElementMenu' I want to interact with an element of the file c.html. The thing is that when I click on that element, I can see that the event is called, but the other element is not found.

At first I had b.html and c.html together, but for some reasons I needed to split it. I thought of splitting it when I loaded them, but didn't find a comfortable way.

** Edited

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () { // in b.html
    // open sidebar
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active'); // in c.html
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some examples of how you are calling the elements in c.html (selectors, ect) would be helpful. Also keep in mind that if c.html hasn't loaded yet the elements won't be on the page. Furthermore, depending on when you try to add the event listeners then the elements might not be there if that is something you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. In both b.html and c.html I was importing the same js. So when I was making the click, it was toggleing twice the class of the element, so no difference was made.

Sorry for the bother